# I'm getting the following runtime error. Please help me figure out why

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, runtimeexception

I'm developing an app with Material Design.

After running the below code & tapping on 'About' option from the menu, the app is crashing & I'm running into the following exceptions:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.abc.xyz/com.abc.xyz.AboutActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference`

Here's my AboutActivity.java file's code:

```
public class AboutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

        SpannableString s = new SpannableString("About");
        s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "Pacifico.ttf"), 0, s.length(),
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(s);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_about, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

As I'm new to material design, I really don't know what to do here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the toolbar widget in your "activity_about.xml"?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  android:id=”@+id/my_awesome_toolbar”
  android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
  android:layout_width=”match_parent”
  android:minHeight=”?attr/actionBarSize”
  android:background=”?attr/colorPrimary” />
```

Also you have a Toolbar toolbar; variable which is redundant. remove it if you are not using it.

Try:
remove the call to getsupportactionbar.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer gave me a hint. I have figured it out now!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a null pointer exception simply indicates you are trying to access an item that isnt yet defined or initialised. Try this

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

You should paste you layout file here to provide  more details

Answer (score 0):

It's null because you are using toolbar in your layout (I see a Toobar object in your code). That means, probably your theme is a `.NoActionBar` theme. So, as you used Toolbar, you have to set that toolbar as `ActionBar`. Then you can use that `ActionBar` and apply whatever method you want to invoke. You can initialize the Toolbar with the following code snippet.

```
private void initToolbar() {
    final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setTitle("Your title");
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```